# Setting up a Flask app that uses headed Selenium on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I have a flask app that uses selenium under the hood to do certain things. I intend to deploy the Flask application to an Ubuntu server. However, I was wondering if a selenium web browser was run, would it be headed or headless?

I SSH into the Ubuntu server and then install python pip. Once I install python pip, I install virtualenv and git clone my code into the sourve venv/bin/activate. I install all my requirements (including selenium)

I then install chrome like this:

`sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo echo "deb [arch=amd64]  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable`

and then I install chromedriver like this:

`wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver`

My Flask application looks like this:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging, time, sys
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect
messages = {}
lo = {}
task_log = {}
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')
socketio = SocketIO(app)
@app.route('/activity',methods=["GET"])
def run():
    browser.get("https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/just-in")
    for x in range (0,1):
        try:
            link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="NavigationMenu-0"]/div/div[''' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + ''']/a[''' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + ''']''')
            href = link.get_attribute("href")
            browser.get(href)
            print(f'{Fore.GREEN}{str(datetime.datetime.now())}  - [INFO] Went to a random section')
        except:
            print(f'{Fore.RED}{str(datetime.datetime.now())}  - [ERROR] Failed to navigate to a random section')
            return "Pre Activity Error Code 0"
        try:
            if activity == "basic":
                for x in range (0,random.randint(1,10)):
                    browser.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {random.randint(1,1900)})")
                    try:
                        browser.find_element_by_class_name("bx-button").click()
                        print(f'{Fore.GREEN}{str(datetime.datetime.now())}  - [INFO] Clicked close button')
                    except:
                        print(f'{Fore.RED}{str(datetime.datetime.now())}  - [ERROR] Failed to click close button or button was not present')

                    time.sleep(random.randint(1,10))
        except:
            return "Pre Activity Error Code 1"
```

So after I installed selenium + chromedriver and the rest of the things, will selenium be run as headed or headless? Is there any way to force it to be headed?

Thanks

P.S (Is my installation process of selenium + chromedriver correct? I used a tutorial for it, so just want to make sure)

Answer (score 2):

You did not post the part of code that defines the actual browser instance.

In order to run Selenium on a server you will need to create a virtual display.
You can do that using [PyVirtualDisplay](https://github.com/ponty/pyvirtualdisplay), with either [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), [Xephyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr) or [Xvnc](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/xvnc.html).

After setting up your virtual display you can run Selenium with Chromedriver in headless mode like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

or if you want to run it without headless:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

You can read more about Chromedriver capabilities [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll be sure to try this out and see if it works!